# RGBDToolKit calibrate correspondence cannot display the live view by my canon digital camera

Tags: kinect, capture, camera-calibration

Hi~ I am trying to calibrate my depth camera with my digital camera.. but I meet some problem using the RGBDKinectCapture...

1、why the calibrate correspondence cannot show the RGB view from my digital camera?? (canon EOS 600D)
I have set it the live view mode..

2、it cannot　recognize　my kinect(1414) on Win7 By the example application (download from the RGBToolKit.com),
and I cannot run the source on Windows,just say the error 'enable_if' also mean the std::tr1::enable_if...

3、What is the methods of taking live preview for （all)　the HD camera in RGBToolKit ??
is it without the SDK of camera??
which methods it based on??
which class?  and I want to debug　it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry ... I see now...

1、the `RGBDToolkit` doesnot display the live preview of the HD camera.... it just load its video....

２、I　cannot run the example on windows because it run with the different sdk for kinect ...（the source has give the sdk..）